# proper jQuery code is not working in webdriver

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, webdriver

I'm migrating our Selenium test to WebDriver and there is a test which use jQuery to identify how much element are in a certain place. This code is working fine with Selenium1 but it is not working with WebDriver. When I say that 'it is not working' I mean that it returns a very big and ugly *null* instead of the desired 3 as string. However, If I run it with Selenium1 than I got the desired 3 as string.

I googled around but I haven't find anything which could help to solve this issue.

The examples are not the real code, they are just examples. If I run the original code in firebug than it always works fine.

The html code:

```
<div id='listOfElements'>
  <div class='items'>
    <ul class='items'>
        <li class='listedElements'>elem 1</li>
        <li class='listedElements'>elem 2</li>
        <li class='listedElements'>elem 3</li>
        <li class='listedElements'>elem 4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript code:

```
window.$("div[id='listOfElements']>div[class='items']>ul[class='items'] li[class*='listedElements']").length
```

The c# code:

```
public string GetEval(string script)
{
        var js = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        return (string) js.ExecuteScript(script);
}
```

This method always returns with null, however I require the amount of the "listeElements".

Versions: c# 3.5

Webdriver: according to my filesystem I downloaded it around start of March this year and I don't know how can I get the revision number of it.

jQuery: 1.6.2

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to return the value, so if the above code is correct:

```
return window.$("div[id='listOfElements']>div[class='items']>ul[class='items'] li[class*='listedElements']").length;
```

You simply need to add the return portion to the front of the string you are to execute.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. Above there is the example c# code where the script variable contains the script. There is a return value. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: The Script variable needs to return the value. Hence the return value preceding your javascript variable.